# Hired for something else been pushed to anything but doing that

Tags: employment, new-jersey

I work in New Jersey. This company hired me to be a tool & Die apprentice. I am the only female tool and die maker. it is supposed to be an apprenticeship where I spent a little bit of time in the each area of the company. I have been machining since February 2016, it is now February 2020.

I have been at this new company now four months.

I was told the training would be 2 to 4 weeks in one area, I started out in quality control. I asked about what was going on and nobody knew what was going on no one will give me a definite answer. At three months I sent a letter to HR asking what is going on. Wanted to a meeting and was told by the head of the company that at 3 months is the time. I'm going to be staying in an area. And that I am awaiting an evaluation to move on to the next area. I've been waiting this evaluation for a month now and nobody is getting back to me.

I feel as if I'm being put on the back burner and not doing what I was hired on to do. Which was to be a tool and die maker, I have not stepped back into any kind of training in the tool & Die room since stepping into this company.

I feel that this is me being hired under false pretenses and that I am being pushed on the back burner.

and I don't want to say that it's because I'm female but I'm also the only female tool and die maker this company has ever hired.

If I decide to quit will I be able to collect unemployment for any of this?

Comment: My advice would be to start looking for another job, once you have secured that, then quit. Typically you can't collect unemployment benefits if you quit, so just hang onto the paycheck until you find another job. Call in sick if you have to miss for interviews, worst that could happen is they fire you and then you can collect unemployment.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Note that you also can't collect unemployment if you are fired for cause, and missing excessive work might be "cause".